# How to optimize limit offset when I join multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here's the format of mysql code

```
select a,b,c 
from table1 
left join table2 on x=y 
left join table3 on m=n
limit 100000, 10
```

I know know to optimize limit when I have a large offset. But I couldn't find the solution to optimize the one with multiple tables, is there any way to make my query faster?

Comment: Do you need "LEFT"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, offsets and limits are unpredictable unless you include `ORDER BY` clauses in your query. Without `ORDER BY`, your SQL server is allowed to return result rows in any order it chooses.

Second, Large offsets and small limits are a notorious query-performance antipattern.  There's not much you can to do make the problem go away.

To get decent performance, it's helpful to rethink why you want to use this kind of access pattern, and then try to use `WHERE` filters on some indexed column value.

For example, let's say you're doing this kind of thing.

```sql
select a.user_id, b.user_email, c.user_account
from table1 a
left join table2 b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
left join table3 c on b.account_id = c.account_id
limit whatever
```

Let's say you're paginating the query so you get fifty users at a time. Then you can start with a `last_seen_user_id` variable in your program, initialized to `-1`.

Your query looks like this:

```sql
select a.user_id, b.user_email, c.user_account
from (
        select user_id 
          from table1 
         where user_id > ?last_seen_user_id?
         order by user_id
         limit 50
     ) u
join      table1 a on u.user_id = a.user_id
left join table2 b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
left join table3 c on b.account_id = c.account_id
order by a.user_id
```

Then, when you retrieve that result, set your `last_seen_user_id` to the value from the last row in the result.

Run the query again to get the next fifty users. If `table1.user_id` is a primary key or a unique index, this will be fast.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this solution may be the optimize solution for me. I was initially thinking about to create a new table to have an index, but it costs so much space.