MySQL Query result Fetch Time is way beyond than Execution Time, how to Solve this?
I am using MySQL 8.0.27-18, with InnoDB as engine. I have a huge database, with few tables containing 100M+ rows in them. For example: TABLE_A with 110M and TABLE_B with 300M+ rows. Sometimes I had to join these tables in fact, and the even worst part is, need to perform SORTing on the results.
Instead of going with complex queries, I wanted to start with a simple query like the SELECT statement below,
SELECT MERCH_NUM,TRANS_DATE, TRANS_AMOUNT, ETC...  FROM TABLE_A WHERE MERCH_NUM = 'XXXXYYYYZZZZ' ;
This table TABLE_A have 110M rows, and the given MERCH_NUM have ~9M rows. Also, we have an Index on the MERCH_NUM  column too.
Now, I can able to execute this query at the cost of Minutes. So, when I looked at statistics, I see below.
Duration / Fetch
0.78 sec / 270.782 sec
As I understood, MySQL took less than 1 sec to complete the query execution but took forever to fetch or retrieve or transfer the results data to client, If I am not wrong.
This fetch part became a huge bottleneck to my application now.
What is causing this huge fetch times, particularly when dealing with huge data? And, How to resolve this?
P.S: Our server has 24GB of RAM allocated.

It could be a limitation of network transfer speed. What can you tell us about the network link between the client and the server? For example, is it within the same datacenter? Or is it going over a slow link between regions? What is the size of the result measured in bytes instead of rows?

look for explain SELECT to see what is happening, maybe it takes the wrong indesx, also there are other types of indexes which you should test

@nbk That will affect execution time, not fetch time.

How much data is being fetched?

@Barmar  without seeing the explain it will be hard to tell and we don't know niothing about his table, there could be hundreds of columns full with data, so that it will  get gigabytes on data

@nbk, checked the EXPLAIN, optimizer picking the right Index of MERCHANT NUM column, as expected. As Barmar mentioned, if there are such issues, it will affect the Execution time too as per my knowledge.

the 9 million rows coud conatains lots of data, so that you must pull gigabytes though the network, but mist server are conncted by gigybit ethernet or even faster. So we have two unknowns one is your hardware second your data, but fivwe minutes is long, so i would guess slow network

@nbk EXPLAIN only explains how it executes the query. Where would it have any information about the fetch time?

Are you executing this query in Workbench? The 0.78 is not necessarily the time to complete the query, it is the time to first row. Unless the rows are huge it is highly unlikely that the 270.782 is actually fetch time, it is more likely combination of execution and fetch time.

Please post TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT ....... so we can see what the optimizer did with your query request.

Hey @WilsonHauck, here is the explain plan for my simple select statement
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,Extra
1,SIMPLE,,NULL,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,100.00,"Using where"
1,SIMPLE,"my_table_1",NULL,ref,IX_M_NBR_INDX,IX_M_NBR_INDX,9,.MRCH_ACCT,173,100.00,NULL
2,MATERIALIZED,"my_table_2",NULL,ref,"MRCH_ACCT_IDX,HQ_MRCH_ACCT_IDX",HQ_MRCH_ACCT_IDX,9,const,928,100.00,"Using index condition"

Please post the exact query COMPLETE TEXT that was input to the EXPLAIN SELECT .....  for analysis.

@WilsonHauck, HERE IT IS
SELECT TRAN_ID,MERCHANT_NBR,TRANS_DATE,TRAN_TYPE,ACCT_NUM,CARDHOLDER_NAME FROM TABLE_A WHERE MERCHANT_NBR IN
(SELECT MRCH_ACCT FROM TABLE_B WHERE HQ_MRCH_ACCT = 'XXXXYYYYZZZZ') ;

@Barmar, the size of data is being transferred for this specific query result is less than 400 MB

@user1191247, that's strange, I mean I learned a new thing. Earlier I though Duration is the complete query execution time. But no, as you said, Workbench provided the Duration as the time taken to fetch the Very first record from the complete list. But not the entire execution time. I have validated this by executing the queries in command line. And applying LIMIT , OFFSET. The deeper I go into rows (using OFFSET), the more time itis taking to respond.

@gouthV_  Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_a;  and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE table_b; for analysis.

What will you be doing with the 9M rows?  That is a lot to send to the client.

Hi @RickJames, It's a kind off transactions report, and that 9M rows report is not every time. It can be more or less based on the filtered criteria. All these filtered records will be accessed some other backend application to be exported as CSV file. Also, whatever the no. of rows filtered. we need to SORT them dynamically (provided as filter section to user)

IN ( SELECT ... ) is quite inefficient.  Can you turn tha into a JOIN?  It sounds like the system is giving the user too much flexibility in constructing the query -- heading to inefficient queries on the large table.

@RickJames, Thanks for understanding the Pain :-/

@RickJames, and, yes, JOIN is my first approach, not the IN. That part was one of my analysis part. Even with the JOIN, I could not see much improvement. System expecting the whatever response in quick intervals like max 10 sec.

Getting the first row of your result set is a subsecond operation, so that indicates an index was used to satisfy your query.
Getting the rest of the rows looks like it took 4.5 minutes. That indicates your result set had many rows and a large volume of data. It looks from comments like you're fetching nine megarows?
A lot of factors can slow the fetching of large volumes of data. It has to move over the network, for one thing. The program receiving it has to do something with it, for example writing it to a file, or maybe allocating RAM for it. The fetch step can't complete until your program reads the last row. But you didn't mention what your program does with the data, so it's hard to know exactly what the cause of your slowdown is.
At any rate, there's no weird SQL voodoo that makes bulk data transfers instantaneous. You probably should consider a different way of getting your results that doesn't involve transferring megarows. Often, the queries you call "complex" can be satisfied quite quickly with appropriate indexes.
Or, simply be prepared for such operations to take time.

Thanks Jones, for responding. Learned a new thing from the response to this post about the Duration time. I understood more when I tried the queries with LIMIT, OFFSET. The deeper I go into the result set (using offset/ LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 100000) the longer query response takes. Then I got to know there not much impact from the Fetch time in my case.

Do you know where I am missing ?  My application will apply filters like Date Range and Merchant Number, and the response should be SORTED with various columns like DATE or HOLDER NAME or any other numeric/alphanumeric columns.

This problem is called "query pagination." It is a notoriously difficult problem to solve in a way that gives the flexibility you want.  Here is a way I have tried to mitigate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67833698/how-to-optimize-limit-offset-when-i-join-multiple-tables/67835619#67835619

Need these indexes:
B:  INDEX(HQ_MRCH_ACCT, HQ_MRCH_ACCT)  -- in this order
A:  INDEX(MERCHANT_NBR)

If those don't help, please edit the Question to include SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN SELECT.
